# Почему на одной учетной записи (основной) есть некоторые программы, а на другой — нет?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Так как я хочу лучше разбираться в системе и прочее, то мой вопрос заключается в следующем.

Почему на одной учетной записи (основной) есть некоторые программы, а на другой — нет?

- Первую учётку создал чисто для учёбы, дабы не отвлекаться на лишнее.
- Вторая учетная запись установлена как администратор (также, как и первая) и родительского контроля также нет.

Comment: У каждого пользователя свои папки, хоть я не уверен насчет программ.